# Angular 9 $localize and xi18n: "Tagged template expressions are not supported in metadata"

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization

My latest Angular project will be published in four languages. Therefor I prepared the app to include `@angular/localize` as described here:

- https://angular.io/guide/i18n
- https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/12/10/angular-localize/

**Setup**

```
Angular: 9.0.7
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... elements, forms, language-service, localize
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.900.7
@angular-devkit/core              9.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.0.7
@angular/cdk                      9.1.3
@angular/google-maps              9.1.3
@ngtools/webpack                  9.0.7
@schematics/angular               9.0.7
@schematics/update                0.900.7
rxjs                              6.5.4
typescript                        3.7.5
webpack                           4.41.2
```

**angular.json**

```
// ...
"projects": {
    // ...
    "my-project": {
        "i18n": {
            "sourceLocale": "de-DE",
            "locales": {
                "fr": {
                    "translation": "messages.fr.xlf",
                    "baseHref": "/fr/"
                },
                "it": {
                    "translation": "messages.it.xlf",
                    "baseHref": "/it/"
                },
                "en": {
                    "translation": "messages.en.xlf",
                    "baseHref": "/en/"
                }
            }
            // ...
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true
    }
}
```

In order to translate strings in code ( e.g. route paths ), I used the new function `$localize`, such as:

```
// ...
export class Translations {
    static paths: TranslatedPathsInterface = {
        // App Routing
        home: $localize`startseite`,
        team: $localize`mitarbeiter`,
        about: $localize`ueber-uns`
        // ...
    };
}
```

This is working fine when serving the app with `ng serve`. The problem arises when I want to extract the marked strings with `ng xi18n` for translation. In the console, the same error occurres several times:

```
ERROR in src/app/shared/translations.ts(39,15): Error during template compile of Translations
Tagged template expressions are not supported in metadata.
```

which basically tells me that the compiler does not like the `$localize` function.

I updated all packages. But now, I am at a loss.

Any hints would be much appreciated! What else can I try?

---

**Update 2020-03-23**

I did some more research and noticed that this error only occurres when using in combination with route path definitions. Any other translations are working fine.

So this works:

```
const something = $localize`etwas`;
```

This does not work:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: $localize`startseite`,
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: $localize`startseite`,
        component: HomeComponent
    }
    // ...
];

@NgModule( {
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot( routes, routerOptions ) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
} )
// ...
```

Comment: Have the same error. Did you managed how to fix it ? Localize module worked for me for about month ago and today i have received this error

Comment: Not yet. I noticed only that the error ocurres only when using inside route definitions (see edited answer).

Comment: Yep, but it's definitely worked for me at the start of March. Not sure what's changed

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for this issue. Looks like if you will wrap your translation with function compiler will not throw error. Example:

```
const getTranslation = () => {
  return $localize`:@@title.tasks:Tasks`;
};

export const taskRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ListTaskComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'List',
      title: getTranslation(),
      status: true,
      description: 'List of tasks',
    }
  }
];
```

Seems to that it's an issue in `@angular/localize` package, but until they will fix it can be done in such way

Another solution may be in skipping ts files from licalization compilation, but i didn't find such option in `ng i18n`

Comment: Your solution worked only when serving the app with `ng serve`. When extracting strings for translation with `ng xi18n` the same error still arises. I am a bit confused, since according to this issue, Google does not require an URL to be translated: https://github.com/robisim74/angular-l10n/issues/233#issuecomment-467582457

Comment: I’m extracting strings with ng i18n-extract and it’s works pretty fine. Not sure about xi18n because I have not test it